# Full Text Not Showing in PowerBI Column

Tags: powerbi

I have a text column called **week_of_release** that is formatted as "ww-yyyy". The data source is an SQLite database.

However, the column only shows the week. For example, "02-2020" would show as "2" or "10-2008" would show as "10". How can I load the entire date? Ultimately, I want to chart YoY by week, so I plan to create new columns for year and week.

[image]

Comment: I guess the source data is just a digit, and SQL format it so that it will show `10-2018` in your case, when you import data in BI, therefore it only 10 in your case, To solve this issue, just add new column to join week and year will do

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. Thanks